# Java Maven MOJO - getting information from project POM

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml, mojo

I am working on a maven plugin. I seem to have a hard time figuring out, what would be a good way to get POM information from project in which you execute the MOJO ?

For instance if I execute my mojo in another maven project I would like to get project name or some other parameters.

And one more thing, there is a context MAP in AbstractMojo.java class there is private Map pluginContext, could someone correct me if I am wrong but this is suppose to be used for passing information between mojos ?

Comment: You should clearly specify what do you want and where do you need to access this info. The project information is available in the pom by default

Comment: The first question i always ask in relationship with creation of plugins is: What would you like to achieve? are you sure you need to write a plugin? Furthermore take a look into other plugins for example, maven-assembly-plugin, maven-javadoc-plugin etc to see how they work etc.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can inject the current maven project into your mojo with a field declared like this:

```
/**
 * @parameter default-value="${project}"
 * @required
 * @readonly
 */
MavenProject project;
```

The projects name is then available by simply calling `project.getName()`.
To use this API, you need to add the `maven-project` artifact as a dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-project</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.6</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Works for me in maven 3.0.3; add the dependency then inject the project!

Comment: I think I found this answer elsewhere on the net but was confused by the fact that it was injected by adding of a previously unknown (to my project) dependency.   This clears it up perfectly, thanks.

Comment: According to [Tutorial: How to Create a Maven Plugin](https://dzone.com/articles/tutorial-create-a-maven-plugin) it's a:`maven-core`: „_needed when injecting the Maven Project into a plugin_“ (Apparently [since 2013](https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.apache.maven/maven-core). The [latest version of a:`maven-project` is from 2010](https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.apache.maven/maven-project)). And [the annotation is different, too](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63320868/1744774).

Answer (score 22):

```
@Component
private MavenProject project;
```

also works (more succinctly and intuitively) if using the new `maven-plugin-annotations`, which is the default for new mojos created from `maven-archetype-plugin`.

*EDIT* (thanks to @bmargulies): although the `@Component` Javadoc as of 3.2 suggests using it for `MavenProject`, apparently that is deprecated and the suggestion is dropped as of 3.3; the [idiom suggested](http://maven.apache.org/plugin-tools/maven-plugin-tools-annotations/index.html) by `maven-plugin-tools-annotations` (as of 3.3) is something like this (both seem to work):

```
@Parameter(defaultValue="${project}", readonly=true, required=true)
private MavenProject project;
```

Comment: OK; what is recommended instead (for plugins using the new API)?

Answer (score 15):

The preferred syntax is now:

```
@Parameter(defaultValue = "${project}", required = true, readonly = true)
MavenProject project;
```

You will have to add a dependency for `maven-project` to your plugin's pom:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-project</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.6</version>
</dependency>
```

(Thanks to others who have supplied this information already. This answer combines them in one place.)

Comment: Maybe for the @Parameter annotation you would like to add the maven-plugin-annotations artifact.

Comment: According to [Tutorial: How to Create a Maven Plugin](https://dzone.com/articles/tutorial-create-a-maven-plugin) it's a:`maven-core`: „_needed when injecting the Maven Project into a plugin_“ (and apparently already [since 2013](https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.apache.maven/maven-core). The [latest version of a:`maven-project` is from 2010](https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.apache.maven/maven-project)). And [the annotation is different, too](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63320868/1744774).

Answer (score 3):

See [Tutorial: How to Create a Maven Plugin](https://dzone.com/articles/tutorial-create-a-maven-plugin):

#### POM

```xml
        <dependency>
            <!-- needed when injecting the Maven Project into a plugin  -->
            <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.3</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
```

#### Mojo

```java
@Parameter(property = "project", readonly = true)
private MavenProject project;
```

Answer (score -1):

`maven-project` for maven 2.x version was replaced with `maven-model` from version maven 3.x, so for new project, use

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-model</artifactId>
  <version>3.6.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Using this instead of [a:`maven-core`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63320868/1744774): „_MavenProject cannot be resolved to a type_“